# How to change offeredby/developer information in chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I just created a chrome extension, I wanted to know how to change the "offered by" and "developer" information. Check the screenshot below I have underlined the information I am referring to.

[image]

I found this one old SO thread - [How to specify author of Extension in Manifest file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391567/how-to-specify-author-of-extension-in-manifest-file).

And I have tried something like this

```
{
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icons/logo.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_title": "Timezone Convertor"
   },
   "description": "The all in one, timezone plugin you had been waiting for!",   
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Timezone Convertor",
   "permissions": [ "storage", "tabs", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
   "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
   "version": "1.5",
   "authors": [{"name": "Ali Rizvi", "email": "example@gmail.com"}, {"name": "Yasser R Shaikh", "email": "example@gmail.com"}]
}
```

But it doesnt work. Google's manifest documentation also doesnt have much information about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Those were in manifests v1 (Also explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391567/how-to-specify-author-of-extension-in-manifest-file)). For v2 and v3 extensions they are changed in the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard.

**Instructions updated 2023:**

1. Visit https://chrome.google.com/webstore/devconsole and login
2. Your account settings can be accessed by clicking the "Account" button in the upper left corner

[image: A screenshot of the Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard account settings page]

Comment: Aha! Thanks. Can it be controlled per plugin by any chance ?

Comment: @Yasser Well, this setting is overridden per store item if you select a verified website in the item settings - it will then be "offered by \[link to website\]". But no, you can't have arbitrary text per-item.

Comment: @Yasser Actually, no, I'm wrong. You can create a Google Group and transfer your extension to that "publisher". Which can have an independent name. But you lose direct control over the extension - anyone in that group can control it and AFAIK you can't transfer back, not automatically anyway. See [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/publish#set-up-group-publishing). Of note: you can only create 1 such group publishing account, but can be member of several.